# Comparing multiple variables against each other?

Tags: python

Hello I have a random question, this is my first post so I apologize if my etiquette is wrong :P

I'm making a race in python, right now I have 4 "cars" and each round they roll between a 1 and 10 and after the round I would like to display something like "carX is in the lead with a roll of Y" I'm kind of lost on how to compare the rolls of each car and print out a certain text depending on which one is the highest.

I appreciate your time,

Comment: Please be more specific. You should include some sample data, and the expected output.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to compare 2 Varibales? How to print them? Be more specific. :)

Comment: its difficult for anyone to help you or give you an answer when we dont know what your code looks like or how your data is generated/stored

Comment: Just sort them descending by roll value and take the one at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, you're looking for an "argmax" implementation.
Meaning you have some N values (rolls), corresponding with N indices (cars), and you want to find which index contains the highest value.

Any way, since you didn't mention it, I'm going to assume that if several values are the maximal (several cars got the same, highest roll), then the first of these is considered the winner.

In your case, given N=4, you can just compare all variables. This gives you 4 cases (one for each car winning) with 3 comparisons each. Actually 3 cases because if the first 3 did not win then defiantly the fourth did.
Each case would look like:

```
if car_1 >= car_2 && car_1 > car_3 && car_1 > car_4:
    print("Car 1 is in the lead with a roll of {}".format(car_1))
```

**This is a horrible way to do it**. So let's first turn the cars into a list of cars

```
list_cars = [car_1, car_2, car_3, car_4]
```

You can use the already existing argmax function defined in numpy, but let's see how for this simple case you can do that without numpy.

Since the default 'max' function would only give you the value (roll) and not the car who`s value it is, we will give the function instead a list of indices for list_cars, and a key that says for each index, use value of the corresponding car instead. so:

```
func = lambda idx: list_cars[idx]
best_car = max(range(len(list_cars)), key = func)
```

Here 'func' defines a lambda function that for each index in the list of cars returns the value for the car, and range(len(list_cars)) gives a list of numbers from 0 to the length of list_cars, so it's [0, 1, 2, 3].

The result, 'best_car' will be a number between 0 and 3 which is the car whose value is the highest. Then you just print

```
print("Car {} is in the lead with a roll of {}".format(best_car + 1, list_cars[best_car]))
```

We print the number of the car using best_car+1 since indexes count from 0, and the cars are counted from 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need some primitive "data-structure" for storing the actual results of race.
Then compute the highest points+select the contestants with highest points.
Converting it to python:

```py
from random import randint
# roll will generate numbers (uniformly) between LO,HI (HI is inclusive)
LO,HI=1,10
roll=lambda : randint(LO,HI)

n=4
# generate the participiants of the race
# here the first element is the cumulative point
parti=[[0,"car"+str(i)] for i in range(n)]
print(parti)

R=10 # num of rounds
r=0
while r<R:
  r+=1
  for i in range(n):
    parti[i][0]+=roll()
  # compute the top point
  mx=max(v[0] for v in parti)
  # select the top contestants
  top=','.join([v[1] for v in parti if v[0]==mx])
  # report the state
  print('after the {0:d}. round {1:s} on the top with {2:d} points'.format(r,top,mx))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, each round you want to print out the name of leading Car. You can accomplish that by creating a dictionary of Cars where the **key** is the name of the Car and **value** is the Cars position. Each round just update the value of all the cars and find the leading car using max() function.

Sample code:

```
import random

number_of_rounds = 10
cars = {'Car1': 0, 'Car2':0, 'Car3':0,'Car4':0} #dictionary of cars

for round in range(1,number_of_rounds+1):
    for car in cars:
        roll_value = random.random()*9 + 1 # get the random value from 1 to 10
        roll_value = int(roll_value) #convert to int
        cars[car] = cars[car] + roll_value
    print cars
    leading_car = max(cars, key=cars.get) # find the key with highest value
    print leading_car + " is in the lead with a roll of " + str(round)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I can't comment as I have low rep, but I have a possible solution: if you just want to check and output the answer, you can use a while loop.

```
# I don't know exactly what you're using but you define your vars up here!
carX = 2
carY = 5
carZ = 3
carN = 7

# Checks every round to see if carX is in the lead
while (carX > carY and carX > carZ and carX > carN):
    print(f"Car X is in the Lead with a roll of {carX}!")
    # Re-roll and add the values again

# Checks if carY is in the lead
while (carY > carX and carY > carZ and carX > carN):
    print(f"Car Y is in the Lead with a roll of {carY}!")
    # Re-roll and add the values again

while (carZ > carX and carZ > carY and carZ > carN):
    print(f"Car Z is in the Lead with a roll of {carZ}!")
    # Re-roll and add the values again

while (carN > carX and carN > carY and carN > carZ):
    print(f"Car Z is in the Lead with a roll of {carZ}!")
    # Re-roll and add the values again
```

I'm sure there are simpler and more elegant ways, but this is just what I think of when I see it, also you might need to add more cases for ties and other exceptions.